# Rewrite pretty url using internal redirect

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to setup a pretty url by internally redirecting,
    `http://test.agency.com/private`  to
    `http://test.agency.com/index.html?//private`

it works when i give **R** my htaccess is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^$"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html?//$1 [QSA,L,R]
```

When it try to maintain pretty url and internally redirect using

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^$"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html?//$1 [QSA,L,P]
```

It is not working, these are the logs i get

```
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/agencytest/private -> 
private
[perdir /var/www/html/agencytest/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to 
uri 
'private'
[perdir /var/www/html/agencytest/] rewrite 'private' -> 
'/index.html?//private'
split uri=/index.html?//private -> uri=/index.html, args=//private
[perdir /var/www/html/agencytest/] escaped URI in per-dir context 
for 
proxy, /index.html -> /index.html
[perdir /var/www/html/agencytest/] forcing proxy-throughput with  
http://agencytest.vignets.com/index.html
[perdir /var/www/html/agencytest/] go-ahead with proxy request 
proxy:http://agencytest.vignets.com/index.html?//private [OK]
[perdir /var/www/html/agencytest/] strip per-dir prefix: 
/var/www/html/agencytest/index.html -> index.html
[perdir /var/www/html/agencytest/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to 
uri 
'index.html'
[perdir /var/www/html/agencytest/] pass through 
/var/www/html/agencytest/index.html
```

Please note `private` can be any string